# Let $K,L$ be convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $(K \cup L)$ is convex. If $x \in K, y \in L$, then $[x,y] \cap (K \cap L) \neq \emptyset$.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-hulls

> Let $K,L$ be convex bodies in $\mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $(K \cup L)$ is convex. If $x \in K, y \in L$, then $[x,y] \cap (K \cap L) \neq \emptyset$.

Here convex bodies are defined to be non-empty, compact and convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I’m looking for a simple argument to verify this statement. The interesting case is of course when $x,y \notin (K \cap L)$. If the statement does not hold then any point on $[x,y]$ would be in either $K$ or $L$, but not both. I suppose then I should get a sequence of points on the line segment $[x,y]$ that tend to either $x$ or $y$, which would lead to a contradiction. But the argument becomes a bit too convoluted. I’d appreciate some help.

Comment: Thanks. I actually had to try hard to fit that question into the title.

Comment: What if $K = (-\infty, 0]$ and $L = (0, \infty)$? They a both convex, as  is their union. But the intersection is empty, so that the conclusion can not be satisfied (e.g. with $x=-1$ and $y=+1$). – Or did you mean *closed* convex sets?

Comment: I’ve just checked the text again and the author defines convex bodies to be non-empty, compact and convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. So yes, $K$ and $L$ are both closed.

Comment: I would suggest to clarify that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $[x, y] \subset K \cup L$ because the union is convex.

Now assume that $[x,y] \cap (K \cap L) = \emptyset $. Then
$$
[x,y] = \bigl([x,y] \cap K \bigr) \cup \bigl([x,y] \cap L \bigr)
$$
is a partition of the segment into nonempty, disjoint, and closed subsets, which is a contradiction to $[x, y]$ being *connected.*